# Points distribution in n-dimension

Tags: matlab, math, geometry, distribution

How to distribute the points to be like Fig.A

This matlab code for Fig. B :

```
N = 30;   % number of points
r = 0.5; % r = radius 
d = 50;  % dimension
C_point = 0; % center point
figure, clf
C = ones(1, d) * C_point;
C_rep = repmat( C,N,1);
X = randn(N,d); 
s2 = sum(X.^2,2) ;
radius = r * (rand(N,1).^(1/d));  
X = X.*repmat(radius./sqrt(s2),1,d) + C_rep; 

%% Plot 2D
t = linspace(0, 2*pi, 100);
x = r*cos(t) + C(1);
y = r*sin(t) + C(2);    
plot(x,y,'b')
hold on
plot(C(1),C(2),'b.', 'MarkerSize', 10) % center point
hold on  
plot(X(:,1), X(:,2),'r.','markersize',10); 
axis equal;rotate3d off; rotate3d on;drawnow;shg; 
hold on
ax = axis;
```

[Source of the code](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9443-random-points-in-an-n-dimensional-hypersphere)

What I should change to be like fig. A

[image]

Comment: What is the problem? Do you just want to randomly spread the point all across the circle (instead of around the centre as in figure B)? What does _in n-dimesion_ in the Title of the question mean? Do you wnat a 3D distribution of the points and a 3D plot?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a direct way of randomly generating points inside an n-dimensional sphere, the correct way to find points inside an arbitrary shape is to generate points within the bounding box, then testing to see if it inside the shape. For example: `X = 2*rand(1,d)-1`, then test if `sum(X.^2)<1`, and if so scale/translate to your target sphere. You need to do this one by one, and repeat until you have enough points. The larger `d`, the less like you are of hitting the unit sphere!

Comment: Here's an alternative approach: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9443-random-points-in-an-n-dimensional-hypersphere

Comment: [This mathoverflow page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87230/picking-random-points-in-the-volume-of-sphere-with-uniform-probability) has the answer. It involves generating a Gaussian distributed variable.

Comment: @Cris Luengo My code is from the link in your comment.
Please check **AMB** and **Kuan-Sung** comments in the link.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog The answers in the link I think for 3-dimensions, in my case I have more than 3 dimentions, it can be 10, 30 or 50.

Comment: @Shdotcom you have not read it properly. It can *trivially* be extended to any number of dimensions

Comment: @Shdotcom ah, right, you take the d-root of the radius. Didn't see that.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog what is the difference between the approach in my question and the approach in **Nate Eldredge**'s answer? in your link. [Please check this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9443-random-points-in-an-n-dimensional-hypersphere)

Comment: I am not familiar with matlab. I'm only providing you with a source which suggests a possible *method*; it is up to you to understand and implement it, if you choose.

Comment: By the way, @Shdotcom, please edit your question to method where you got the code from, add the link to the File Exchange page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP's code computes points uniformly distributed within a d-dimensional box, projects those onto a d-dimensional sphere, then samples the radius to move them inside the d-dimensional ball. This is perfect except that the points inside the box, when projected onto the sphere, do not form a uniform distribution on that sphere. If instead you find random points distributed in a Gaussian distribution, you are guaranteed uniform angle distribution.

First compute points with a Gaussian distribution in `d` dimensions (I do all here with minimal changes to the OP's code):

```
N = 1000;   % number of points
r = 0.5; % r = radius 
d = 3;  % dimension
C_point = 0; % center point
C = ones(1,d) * C_point;
C_rep = repmat(C,N,1);
X = randn(N,d);
```

Note that I use `randn`, not `rand`. `randn` creates a Gaussian distribution.

Next we normalize the vectors so the points move to the sphere:

```
nX = sqrt(sum(X.^2,2));
X = X./repmat(nX,1,d);
```

These points are uniformly distributed, which you can verify by `scatter3(X(:,1),X(:,2),X(:,3)); axis equal` and turning the display around (a 2D rendering doesn't do it justice). This is the reason I set `d=3` above, and `N=1000`. I wanted to be able to plot the points and see lots of them.

Next we compute, as  you already did, a random distance to the origin, and correct it for the dimensionality:

```
radius = r * (rand(N,1).^(1/d));
X = X.*repmat(radius,1,d) + C_rep;
```

`X` now is distributed uniformly in the ball. Again, `scatter3(X(:,1),X(:,2),X(:,3)); axis equal` shows this.

However, if you set `d=50` and then plot only two dimensions of your data, you will not see the data filling the circle. And you will not see a uniform distribution either. This is because you are projecting a 50-D ball onto 2 dimensions, this simply does not work. You either have to trust the math, or you have to *slice* the data:

```
figure, hold on
t = linspace(0, 2*pi, 100);
x = r*cos(t) + C(1);
y = r*sin(t) + C(2);    
plot(x,y,'b')
plot(C(1),C(2),'b.', 'MarkerSize', 10) % center point
axis equal

I = all(abs(X(:,3:d))<0.1,2);
plot(X(I,1), X(I,2),'r.','markersize',10);
```

The `I` there indexes points that are close to the origin in dimensions perpendicular to the first two shown. Again, with `d=50` you will have very few points there, so you will need to set `N` very large! To see the same density of points as in the case above, for every dimension you add, you need to multiply `N` by 10. So for `d=5` you'd have `N=1000*10*10=1e5`, and for `d=50` you'd need `N=1e50`. That is totally impossible to compute, of course.

Comment: would you please suggest a good references that explain all these concepts. Thank you

Comment: I don't have a single reference, this is information I've pieced together over the years. The multi-dimensional Gaussian you can read about on Wikipedia. The root-`d` trick I knew about in 2D, apparently it works in any number of dimensions.

Comment: The root-*d* trick: the volume of a shell at radius *r* + d*r* is proportional to *r^d*. If you sample *r* uniformly, the shell for small *r* will get the same number of points in its small volume as the shell for a larger *r*, with a much larger volume. By sampling *r^d* uniformly (which you get by taking the root-*d* of a uniform variable in the range [0,1]), you assign more points to the larger volume shell, such that the density of points is equal for all *r*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, what if I have M d-dimensional balls, inside each ball we have N points (the points are uniformly distributed). How to uniformly distribute the M d-dimensional balls without collide or overlap with each other?

Comment: @Shdotcom: that's a whole different question, you should probably post a new question for that (or do some research first, I'm sure you'll find code for that too). Note that uniformly distributing the balls without overlap is independent of any randomly placed points inside the balls.

Comment: Sorry, I am not mathematical specialist, would you please explain to me, what do you mean by: "uniformly distributing the balls without overlap is independent of any randomly placed points inside the balls."

Comment: @Shdotcom That means that distributing the balls on the plane and distributing the dots in the balls are two independent things, you place the balls first, and then you fill them with dots. When you go look for a way to distribute balls, ignore that you'll fill them with dots later, it's an irrelevant detail. Will make it easier to find a solution.

Comment: I did that, first I distribute M points (M points represent a center of M balls), then I add 2*r to the center of the next ball to prevent the overlap. , then I fill each ball with N points using the code above. With respect to the center point. Is that correct or not?

Comment: @Shdotcom sure, sounds legit.

Comment: I have posted [another question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48139133/combine-and-divide-d-dimensional-spheres), would you please help me to answer it. Thank you